# How to create a password WITH SPACES via Command Prompt

Tags: passwords, command, cmd, prompt

I found the syntax to change a user password through command prompt. I am using:
net user username password

I have sucessfully changed the password to a regular password. I can not figure out how to change it to a pass-sentence. How would I write the syntax for a password with spaces in it? 
For instance, please explain how I would write "My new password." in cmd...because this doesnt work:
net user testuser2 My new password.

I am sure that it is case sensative, no? If its case sensative for the password, why wont it recognise the sapces as part of the password?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: This question looks like one for superuser.com or serverfault.com

Comment: You mean "passphrase", and I don't think that Windows is setup to accept pass-phrases, only passwords. BUT... you **can** use `%var: =_%` to change the spaces into underscores.

Answer (score 3):

Try surrounding the password with quotation marks, such as:

```
net user username "My new password"
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically you can put the phrase in double quotes ex "My new password" is you have spaces in you command line.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  This answer is similar but worse than the answer already provided.  If you're answering a question that already has a useful answer, please try to improve it somehow